# Case Expression with ABS

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below table: I'm looking for the days between firstDate and EndDate but when EndDate = 09/09/9000 use sysdate.

Table C

```
FirstDate      EndDate        id
 12/28/15     09/09/9000       1
```

I have the below that works but is there a better way to write this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
 id,
 ABS(TO_DATE(C.FirstDate) - TO_DATE(C.EndDate)) AS Between_days

       FROM (SELECT id, FirstDate,
             CASE WHEN  TO_CHAR(C2.EndDate,'MM/DD/YYYY') = '09/09/9000' THEN TRUNC(SYSDATE)
               ELSE C2.EndDate
                 END AS EndDate,
                 C2.ID,                   
              FROM tableC C2 ) C
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it without the derived table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   id,
   CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(EndDate,'MM/DD/YYYY') = '09/09/9000'
        THEN ABS(TO_DATE(FirstDate) - TRUNC(SYSDATE))
        ELSE ABS(TO_DATE(FirstDate) - TO_DATE(EndDate))
   END as Between_days
FROM tableC
```